# Найти разность индексов

Tags: c

Написал функцию нахождения разности индексов max и min элементов. А как найти наибольшую и наименьшую разницу между индексами max и min элементов?
Вот условие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
int indx(int* a, int n) {
    int f = 0;
    int min = a[0];
    int g = 0;
    int max = a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] < min)
            (min = a[i]) && (f = i);
        if (a[i] > max)
           (max = a[i]) && (g = i);
    }
    printf("a[%d] - a[%d] = ", g, f);
    int p = g - f;
    return p;
}
int main()
{
    int A[] = { 1,1,2,3,1,1 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    int x = indx(A, 6);
    printf("%d ", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит разности индексов? Возникает ощущение, что ты не понимаешь, что такое индекс. Как можно найти наибольшую и наименьшую разницу между максимумом и минимумом, объясни мне?

Comment: сам не понимаю условие задачи. возможно имелось в виду не разницу, а разность индексов

Comment: препод похоже равенство зачисляет и в максимумы и в минимумы, либо это его научная работа, либо уже новый год отмечает